# Starting point to build spring-data for own db

Tags: spring, spring-data

What would be a good starting point to build spring-data support for my own db? Is there anything like a blueprint, or a documentation? Or is there any exemplary spring-data implementation which could be used as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to go for that:

- The most obvious one would be having a look at, and/or cloning, one of the existing projects and reimplement what you see there. Please have a look at the [Developer-guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Developer-guide) available.
- A little bit simpler, though more limited, would be building upon [Spring Data KeyValue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue) providing your own flavor of `KeyValueAdapter` and `QueryEngine`. Samples of that can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-aerospike) and [there](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/pull/1).